# One shared settings section for multiple tests and suits?

Tags: robotframework

I woud like to make a Robot Framework project with multiple (levels of) test suits and test cases.

Is it possible to define a list of settings, specifically importing of libraries, resources and global variable (.py files), only once in one place?

As far as I'm aware this is not possible. You have to import libraries, resources and variable files explicitily in each .robot test case file that uses them. The **init** file in a directory can only be used for other settings, not imports.

But I would like to keep things DRY and import resourse that I use everywhere only once and in one place.

Is this not possible, or am I missing something?

Note: I'm still a RF newbie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easily doable, and quite a common pattern - have a resource file, that has all the common keywords, variables, imports of other `robot` or `py` files, etc, and in every test suite - import it.

Say your project's directory structure is like this:

```
root_folder/
├── resources/
│   ├── common_resource.robot
│   ├── helpers.robot
│   ├── specific_page.robot
└── suites/
    ├── login_page.robot
    └── specific_page.robot
```

The file `resources/common_resource.robot` has all those common elements - say, imports `helpers.robot` as a resource.
Every suite file imports the common file; e.g. both `login_page.robot` and `specific_page.robot` start-off with (path-relative) imports:

```
*** Settings ***
# other imports, documentation, etc
Resource            ../resources/common_resource.robot
```

On top of that, each suite imports any other specific keyword files - like `resources/specific_page.robot`.

It's a convention, that once established ("every suite **must** import `common_resource.robot`") is easy to follow.
If there is a new keyword, variable or library that has to be used in all - or most - suites, just add it to the common file, and it will be instantly accessible.